# Error: _in_process.py: 'make' failed returning 2 in buildroot 2023.02.6

Tags: buildroot, pyqt6

Getting following error while compiling buildroot 2023.02.6 after including PYQt6 package in it.

_in_process.py: 'make' failed returning 2

ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_wheel
make: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:293: /home/appl/work/buildroot_us15w/output/build/python-pyqt6-6.5.3/.stamp_built] Error 1

Can you inform me possible reason for it and solution for it.